# How can I update the dynamic cache manually?

Tags: informatica

**Scenario**

```
Source -> Lkp(dim) -> Expr -> 2Targets (Dim Table and Fact table)
```

- Here target dim table is cached and used as dynamic lookup.
- Whenever a row comes from source, it is looked up in the cache.
- If lkp is successful then ID is retrieved and inserted into Fact along with other columns.
- If lkp fails then new ID is generated in the Expr by a Sub Procedure call to database and is inserted into both Dim and Fact table along with other columns.

**Issue**

- The ID since it is not a lookup column, it needs a value to be assigned in dynamic cache.
- I can use the associated expression to set either a static value or a sequence.
- But I need this ID to be generated by the DB which will not happen unless you pass the lkp and get into Expr
- If I use auto sequence from informatica, then the dim table and cache will be out of sync - one getting sequence from informatica and the other from DB.
- I cannot use informatica seq because this mapping will have multiple instances running concurrently.

**Illustration**

### Dim table

```
ID    col1    col2
401   a       1
402   b       3
403   h       8
```

### Lookup

```
ID    col1    col2
401   a       1
402   b       3
403   h       8
```

### Fact Table

```
fcol1    fcol2    fcol3    ID(foreign key to DIM)
aa       11       1        401
bb       33       4        401
dk       44       2        403
```

### Source

```
col1    col2
h       8
v       6
v       6
```

- The first record from source will go smoothly. It will insert a record into fact with ID 403 from lkp

### Fact Table after first record

```
fcol1    fcol2    fcol3    ID(foreign key to DIM)
aa       11       1        401
bb       33       4        401
dk       44       2        403
eo       23       5        403
```

- The second record from source doesn't find a match in the lkp and hence updates the cache instantly.
- Then Expr will execute this logic. If(lkp failed) then call sp(seq_gen) else use the id fetched from lkp
- The new ID will be inserted to both DIM and FACT
- Problem is this newly generated ID is not available to the lookup cache. Instead it uses the value from associated port.

### Fact Table after second record

```
fcol1    fcol2    fcol3    ID(foreign key to DIM)
aa       11       1        401
bb       33       4        401
dk       44       2        403
eo       23       5        403
fa       32       3        404
```

### Dim table after second record

```
ID    col1    col2
401   a       1
402   b       3
403   h       8
404   v       6
```

### Lookup

```
ID    col1    col2
401   a       1
402   b       3
403   h       8
<ap>   v       6
```

- where  is associated port expression. We can write any expression here. How do I bring 404 here. I cannot write Expr expression here as I cannot check if the lookup failed or succeeded.

### Fact Table after third record

```
fcol1    fcol2    fcol3    ID(foreign key to DIM)
aa       11       1        401
bb       33       4        401
dk       44       2        403
eo       23       5        403
fa       32       3        404
ep       53       6        <ap> (I expect 404)
```

Comment: Since you can't generate ID's on Infa side, I would use a dummy Dim id to populate fact table (like -1) and run an update statement after the load is complete. Sending the request for a key and getting the key from DB means a lot of DB calls - this takes time and will slow down the whole process a lot. Read about handling Late Arriving Dimensions.

Comment: If you see last section of my question, I'm using a dummy id which is <ap>. How can one update the fact table with original id unless he has a map between original and dummy ids.